# Image 'href' is not working in PHP

Tags: php

I have a very weird problem while trying to echo href with img...I have done everything what it supposed to be but still can't get the result... here is my coding:

```
while( $oXml->read() ) 
{
    $i = "";
    if( $oXml->name == 'link' ) 
    {
        $i = $oXml->readInnerXML();
    }

    $j ="";
    if( $oXml->name == 'image_link' ) 
    {
        $j = $oXml->readInnerXML();
    }

    $k = "<img src='".$j."'>";
    echo "<a href='".$i."'>".$k."</a><br />";
}
```

Its only showing me the img but in the link its showing the url of the same page...I have figured out the issue why this is not working...the link am trying to fetch is the following

```
http://snapdeal.com/product/gauba-traders-jackly-31in1-screw/851405127
```

While trying to open any link like http://google.com or http://yahoo.com it works only this url is not working...can anyone pleasesuggest me what to do

Comment: check what this($i = $oXml->readInnerXML();) method return in $i?

Comment: what is the output you are getting in href='".$i."'  and $k?

Comment: @jQuery...if i echo $i and $k it shows me proper value

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND...it shows me the value of each vraibles